# Using an asterisk as value in PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm writing a function that takes two parameters, the first being the id of a user (which defaults to %) and the second being which fields should be retrieved (which defaults to *). The first parameter works fine, but for some reason when I try using an asterisk as the value of the parameter for the prepared statement I get odd results (listed below). Is there any reason why I can't use an asterisk in a prepared statement but can use a percent sign? My function is below:

```
public function getMembers($id = '%', $fields = '*') {
    $sql = 'SELECT ?
        FROM members
        WHERE members.member_id LIKE ?;';

    return $this->executeQuery($sql, array($fields, $id));
}
```

and here is the executeQuery function:

```
public function executeQuery($query, array $parameters = array(), $fetch_type = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $result = array();

    $sth = $this->handle->prepare($query);

    if($sth->execute($parameters)) {
        while($row = $sth->fetch($fetch_type)) {
            array_push($result, $row);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And finally the result if I use the default asterisk:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [*] => *
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters behave as values. Field names are identifiers, not values, so what you're doing ends up acting like:

```
SELECT '*' FROM ...
```

which is, of course, useless.

If you need to pass field names into a PDO query, you will need to escape them appropriately and interpolate them into the query. Ideally, though, your code should be structured such that this is not necessary.

Comment: Ah ha, that makes sense. I suppose I'll have to come up with a different method to allow the user to customize what they want returned by the function. Either that or just dump all the fields and allow them to filter out their desired data. Thanks for the help.